# Variable string in string in variable ?? PHP

Tags: php, mysql, string, variables

I am coding a reoccurring sql select with a varying clause. In the clause i have a PHP variable (supposed to be replaced later within a WHILE.

My code:

```
$custaccount_id_clause = "(SELECT DISTINCT(custaccount_id) AS custaccount_id FROM accountcomms_def_tbl a WHERE subagent_def_id = " . '\'$interest_id\'' . " AND agentorder > (SELECT agentorder FROM accountcomms_def_tbl WHERE subagent_def_id = '$subagent_def_id' and custaccount_id = a.custaccount_id))";
```

$subagent_def_id works becuase its already defined.

$interest_id does NOT work because its not defined. I am trying to substitute it with $interest_id later on during a while loop in which I am calling $custaccount_id_clause as part of a while loop:

```
    $allresidual_sql = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(txn_value) as txn_sum, COUNT(DISTINCT(custaccount_id)) AS accounts FROM account_stmnt_tbl WHERE txn_type IN ('Fixed Residual','Variable Residual','One Time Adjustment') AND custaccount_id IN ". $custaccount_id_clause)or die(mysql_error());
```

1. Within the $custaccout_id clause, I have the text '$interest_id' which I want PHP to replace the variable within. It is not replacing the variable.
2. This is a quick example app I am writing for a demo, please dont lecture me about which API I am using, as I wont be coding anything that goes into production! :)

Comment: Are you trying to re-create the functionality of [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)?

Comment: Cartsen, It seems though that forgetting MYSQL, you should be able to put a variable in a string, and then refer to that in another variable: $variable2 = "String " . $variable . " String"; $variable = "Middle"; echo $variable2;

Comment: If you really want to do it that way, [`sprintf()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) is you friend.

Comment: If I understand this correctly I see 2 possibilities: 1) don't create the query string until you know all the variables or 2) use a custom macro string and do a string replacement of your custom macro once you know the correct value. str_replace( '%%%interest_id%%%', $value, $query). I'd opt for the solution 1 as the other is just a dirty hack and your future dev partners will hate you for it.

Comment: sprintf IS MY FRIEND! Thanks Cartsen. smassey, This is throw away to illustrate the commission structure of a deal-higherarcy for which the data will put into a power-point! Basically the audience is meant to suggest numbers we plug in, and it spits out a fancy graph. Nothing should exist after a quick demo! Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to use the first variable you wanted to use ($interest_id) would be to test it and place a null inside instead of the variable in a direct fashion like this:

```
WHERE subagent_def_id = '" . ($interest_id ? $interest_id : null) . "' AND agentorder
```

This should protect you from getting errors about the variable/property not being defined.

The substitution part is what intrigues me... do you mean, at a given point in your structure, replacing `$interest_id` with, let's say, `$my_other_variable`? You could accomplish that if you model the whole SQL query as a string and, depending on a given condition, you re-write it.

Something like this could work (it's just a simple test, adapt it for your needs if you see it fit):

```
$query = ($a ? "SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE `price` > '{$a}';" : "SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE `date_added` < '{$b}' AND price > 20;");
```

That's if I have understood you correctly. Otherwise, I suspect you want to use the `eval()` function for parsing your encoded string and making PHP process your variable as you wish.

Hope that helps